# increase VS's Intellisense suggestion ability when access template parameter

Tags: c++11, templates, resharper, c++17, intellisense

I want to access template parameter.   This code [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3b87911c5a90e16) :-

```
template<int s1,int s2> class Setting{public:
    static const int setting1=s1;
    static const int setting2=s2;
};
class Album{
    public: using Setting_unique  =Setting<1,2>    ;
    public: using Setting_share   =Setting<4,7>    ;
};
template<class Setting_X> class SmartPtr{
    public: void doSomething(){
        if constexpr(Setting_X::setting1==1){
            //                  ^ intellisense sad :(
        }
    }
};
int main(){ SmartPtr<Album::Setting_unique> a; }
```

^ However, the intellisense is not happy with it.
I can't do my `ctrl+space`.

Below is my trick to make Intellisense works again.  It also [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ccc9618a2d8a552) :-

```
class Helper{public:  // **new class**
    int setting1=0;
    int setting2=0;
    public: constexpr Helper(int setting1P,int setting2P)
        : setting1(setting1P), setting2(setting2P){ }
};
template<int s1,int s2> class Setting{
    // **new function**
    public: static constexpr Helper getHelper(){return Helper(s1,s2);}
};
class Album{
    public: using Setting_unique  =Setting<1,2>    ;
    public: using Setting_share   =Setting<4,7>    ;
};
template<class Setting_X> class SmartPtr{
    static constexpr Helper setting = Setting_X::getHelper();
    public: void doSomething(){
        if constexpr(setting.setting1==1){
            //               ^ intellisense happy :) -
            //      It shows "setting1" & "setting2" in a drop-down list.
        }
    }
};
int main(){SmartPtr<Album::Setting_unique> a; }
```

Here is the drop down list I desire :-

[image]

**The problem is** : my code becomes harder to refactor and dirtier.
If I may add a new `s3` in the future, there are more locations of codes waiting to be edited.

How to make the intellisense happy, while keep the maintainability-level?

I am using **Visual Studio 2017** + **Resharper**.
*(optional)* However, it would be cool if the solution doesn't depends on Resharper, or it can be applied to most IDEs as well.

Sorry if this question may sound trivial, but `ctrl+space` is my life.

Comment: There should be [Enable Template IntelliSense](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/06/26/template-intellisense/) option available within recent updates to manually provide an example of template parameter for intellisense.

Comment: @dewaffled Thank, it is useful.  I am not using the most recent VS, though.  If it is promoted to a solution, I will +1 it.  :)